# Django models class relationships

Tags: python, django

In django models, I have 2 classes; Countries and Continents. Each country is linked to Continent with foreign key.

```
class Continent(models.Model):
   countries = [get countries that are linked to this continent here]

class Country(models.Model):
   continent = models.ForeignKey(Continent)
```

How can I get the linked countries in the countries attribute?

In shell I can get the countries using

```
Country.objects.get()
```

But it seems i cannot use class name Country in the attribute of another class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what `related_name`'s are used for in Django.

When creating a `ForeignKey` relationship to another model, you can specify the reverse name of that relation. (i.e the name that the parent model can use to access all its children). Change your model definition to this:

```
class Country(models.Model):
   continent = models.ForeignKey(Continent, related_name='countries')
```

and now from any continent instance, you should be able to call `.countries` on it and get a `queryset` of all countries related to it. ***You don't need to add any extra code to the `Continent` model. Django handles it automatically for you.***

for example:

```
continent = Continent.Objects.get(id=1)
continent.countries.all()  # returns a `queryset` of all related countries
```

Read the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) for more information on what you can do with `related_name`